# How do I update a global variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a project that includes lives, and to do that I have these three functions in the Javascript code:

```js
{
  var lives = 0;
  var function1 = lives + 1;
  var function2 = Math.pow(lives, 3);
  var function3 = function1 * 2;
}

function addLife()
{
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function1;
}
function prize1()
{
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function2;
}
function prize2()
{
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<hr/>
<p id="lives">Lives: 0</p>
<input type=button value="Don't click" onClick="addLife()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 1" onClick="prize1()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 2" onClick="prize2()" />
```

When I run the code the global variable lives does not update. How do I update the variable every time a button is clicked?

Comment: I'm new to Javascript btw so please help me thank you so much :D

Comment: you need to update your variables inside your functions

Comment: how do i  though?

Comment: How would `lives` update? The only time you are assigning a value to it is when you set it to 0 with `lives = 0`

Comment: Your "functions" are **not functions**, but simply primitive values only calculated once at the moment of initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```js
let lives = 0;

const function1 = () => ++lives;
const function2 = () => lives = Math.pow(lives, 3);
const function3 = () => lives = (++lives) * 2;

function addLife() {
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function1();
}

function prize1() {
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function2();
}

function prize2() {
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + function3(); 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>A very safe site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p id="lives">Lives: 0</p>
    <input type=button value="Don't click" onClick="addLife()" />
    <input type=button value="Prize 1" onClick="prize1()" />
    <input type=button value="Prize 2" onClick="prize2()" />

    <!-- Load JS later so HTML loads quickly -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @dionMinecraft I fixed one bug, please update your code! And please if it is not hard for you mark my answer as useful and approve my answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not always calling your functions correctly. Have a look at my version below where functions 1 through 3 modify the global variable `lives`.

```js
// Here is a global variable called `lives`
var lives = 0;

// Here are three functions that will modify the value or `lives` when they are called
function function1 () { lives = lives + 1; } // This one adds 1 to `lives`
function function2 () { lives = Math.pow(lives, 3); } // This one brings `lives` to its third power
function function3 () { function1(); lives = lives * 2; } // This one multiplies `lives` by 2 after adding 1 to it

// This function puts the value of `lives` (at the moment the function is called) into the HTML
function updateLives () {
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;
}
// And as for these last fuctions, they are each associated to a button and just call one `lives`-modifying function followed by `updateLives` to put the result into the HTML
function addLife()
{
  function1();
  updateLives();
}
function prize1()
{
  function2();
  updateLives();
}
function prize2()
{
  function3();
  updateLives();
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<hr/>
<p id="lives">Lives: 0</p>
<input type=button value="Don't click" onClick="addLife()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 1" onClick="prize1()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 2" onClick="prize2()" />
```

And here is another version which takes advantage of the fact that functions can return values:

```js
// Here is a global variable called `lives`
var lives = 0;

// Here are three functions that represent a calculation you'll want to perform on `lives`
function function1 (inputLives) { return inputLives + 1; } // This one adds 1 to whatever value is passed in a returns the result
function function2 (inputLives) { return Math.pow(inputLives, 3); } // This returns the input value brought to its third power
function function3 (inputLives) { return function1(inputLives) * 2; } // This one gets the return value for its input from function1, then multiplies the result by 2

// This function puts the value of `lives` (at the moment the function is called) into the HTML
function updateLives () {
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;
}
// And as for these last fuctions, they are each associated to a button and just call one of the above functions, set the new value for `lives`, and then calls `updateLives` to put the result into the HTML
function addLife()
{
  lives = function1(lives);
  updateLives();
}
function prize1()
{
  lives = function2(lives);
  updateLives();
}
function prize2()
{
  lives = function3(lives);
  updateLives();
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<hr/>
<p id="lives">Lives: 0</p>
<input type=button value="Don't click" onClick="addLife()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 1" onClick="prize1()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 2" onClick="prize2()" />
```

There are many ways to achieve the same thing here, so other answers can be good too, but hopefully this helps explain why things weren't working for you initially: you weren't defining your functions correctly, nor calling them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure to understood your request but I tried to refactor your code here:

```js
var lives = 0;
    
function addLife()
{
  lives ++;
  renderLivesCount();
}
function prize1()
{
  lives = Math.pow(lives, 3);
  renderLivesCount();
}
function prize2()
{
  lives = (lives + 1) * 2;
  renderLivesCount();
}

function renderLivesCount()
{
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "Lives: " + lives;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<hr/>
<p id="lives">Lives: 0</p>
<input type=button value="Don't click" onClick="addLife()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 1" onClick="prize1()" />
<input type=button value="Prize 2" onClick="prize2()" />
```

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the stack snippets feature. Click "Edit" below your answer and then the button that resembles `<>`.